# Somewhat relevant self-advertising in the comments

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

What is the general consensus on the action that should be taken when a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3205479/user3205479?tab=activity&sort=comments) advertises something they've made in the comments of several different posts within the span of a minute? The framework in question is somewhat relevant, but it appears that he just went through the recent questions of a particular tag and commented:

[image]

Comment: Well, you always can flag for mod attention and explain that. Seems to be a valid case caught for spamming in comments.

Comment: It's spam, and [not something they're new to.](https://i.imgur.com/n1bxVsu.png)

Comment: That is excessive self-promotion, whether posted as answers or comments.